# Steam won't launch in Windows 10 dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: steam, linux, windows-10, ubuntu

I have a laptop with dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04). It has been about 2 months that I have been using dual boot. Before I installed Ubuntu 20.04, my Windows 10 had Steam installed. Then I installed Ubuntu 20.04 which works well so far. But on my Windows 10, Steam won't open. Then I disabled the fast startup in Windows 10. Now I can open Steam. But everytime I try to play a game from my library, the game won't launch.

I already tried to re-install the game, but it doesn't work. Then I tried to re-install Steam, and it does not work. Now Steam won't open after I tried to install a game from my libraries. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you get any specific error message? Does it just open and directly close? Is it opening, but in the background? (e.g. you can see it in the task manager, but there is no GUI.)

Comment: @Mixxiphoid It just open and directly close

Comment: Can you check the event viewer of Windows for any error message to include in your post?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I managed to solve the problem, I already add my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by these steps :

1. Update the windows
2. Install my NVIDIA GPU driver from the official website.

I tested it by playing Digimon Cyber Sleuth, and it seems stable so far.